# How to set up 2 boot up configs on Ubuntu for 2 different video drivers?

Tags: ubuntu, video, boot

I am interested in setting up 2 boot configs for my Linux Mint Tessa 19.1 (Ubuntu 18.04) machine with AMD card and AMD drivers that use different video drivers.

History: I think I was using open source AMD drivers initially and video display was great. But with Blender, it would use CPU for rendering and would not use the GPU. I installed drivers for OpenCL from ROCm (https://rocm.github.io/ROCmInstall.html#ubuntu-support---installing-from-a-debian-repository -- lower section titled 'Performing an OpenCL-only Installation of ROCm'). Blender now displays an option to use the GPU for rendering. However, video quality has degraded -- sometimes horizontal splits, movie video looks grainy, and video stopped but sound kept playing in middle of Avengers.

Goal: 2 boot configs: 1) default with regular drivers for watching videos 2) with OpenCL ROCm driver for working with Blender.

Is it possible to configure this? Previously I had a GRUB 2 loader that would choose between Linux and Windows, I was wondering if GRUB 2 can have 2 configs for the video drivers.

Alternatively, I could uninstall the OpenCL rocM dirver, and install when I want to use Blender, but that would be a long way for swapping between the 2.

Comment: [ubuntu.se] would probably be the place to ask this

Comment: Thank you -- I've posted on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190964/how-to-set-up-2-boot-up-configs-on-ubuntu-for-2-different-video-drivers

Comment: AskUbuntu said it's Mint, not Ubuntu, so off topic.